# jQuery Facebox restrict closing

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery Facebox to show a list of possible currencies a user can customise the site to however Facebox allows closing when clicking outside the popup (dark area). I would like to force the user to select a currency and click a button and then close facebox so my question is, is there a way to stop the default close actions (click outside and the cross) so I force the user to click an 'OK' (or whatever) button?

I can then close Facebox programatically (which I already know how).

Comment: What is clode.facebox?

Comment: I don't know what clode.facebox is but I basically meant close programatically

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer

```
$(document).bind('loading.facebox', function() {
    $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox');
    $('#facebox_overlay').unbind('click');
});
```